# How to find fundamental sets to the simple harmonic ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading a chapter on DFQs and a theorem says that an $n$-th order homogenous linear differential equation has at least $n$ linearly independent solutions.
Then, an example is shown:

> The equation for simple harmonic motion is $$\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2}+\omega^2 y=0$$ It has fundamental solutions $y_1(t) = \sin(\omega t)$ and $y_2(t) = \cos(\omega t)$, and a second fundamental set is $z_1(t) = \cos(\omega t)+i\sin(\omega t)$, $z_2(t) = \cos(\omega t)-i\sin(\omega t)$.

Where does the second set come from??

Comment: Please update you question by formatting you equations with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Questions that don't do this typically attract downvotes and are more likely to be closed.

Comment: If your characteristic equation has real solutions, you'll get the first fundamental set. If your characteristic equation has complex solutions, you'll get the second fundamental set. Though, you'd only get the first case for complex $w$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two sets are really almost the same thing, in the sense that they span the same vector space. The set of functions
$$\mathcal V=\{y\in C^2(\mathbb C,\mathbb C):y''+\omega^2y=0\}$$
Is in fact a vector space under the operations of pointwise addition and pointwise scalar multiplication. The two solution sets you have been given are both *bases* of this space. The space is *two dimensional* because each basis only consists of two items. (Actually *proving* the space is two dimensional is a far trickier task so just bear with me here.) What do I mean by basis? Well, when I say that two functions $y_1,y_2$ are a basis for the space it means that if I pick some arbitrary (nonzero) $y\in\mathcal{V}$, then there exist **unique** numbers $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$y=c_1 y_1+c_2y_2$$
It turns out that the functions
$$y_1:t\mapsto \cos(\omega t)~~,~~y_2:t\mapsto \sin(\omega t)$$
Is such a basis. And, the functions
$$z_1:t\mapsto \cos(\omega t)+i\sin(\omega t)~~,~~z_2:t\mapsto \cos(\omega t)-i\sin(\omega t)$$
Is also a basis, which we can prove if we first take it as given that $\{y_1,y_2\}$ is a basis.

---

**PROOF:** We want to prove $\{z_1,z_2\}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{V}$, i.e, for any $y\in\mathcal V$ that $\exists b_1,b_2\in\mathbb C$ such that
$$y=b_1z_1+b_2z_2$$
The proof is simple. Since $\{y_1,y_2\}$ is a basis for $\mathcal V$ by assumption, we know $\exists c_1,c_2\in\mathbb C$ such that
$$y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2$$
However, since
$$z_1=y_1+iy_2~~,~~z_2=y_1-iy_2$$
We can write
$$\begin{bmatrix}
z_{1}\\
z_{2}
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & i\\
1 & -i
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}\\
y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
If we invert the matrix on both sides, we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
-i & i
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
z_{1}\\
z_{2}
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}\\
y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Which yields
$$y_1=\frac{1}{2}(z_1+z_2)~~,~~y_2=\frac{i}{2}(z_1-z_2)$$
Therefore we can write
$$y=\frac{c_1}{2}(z_1+z_2)+\frac{ic_2}{2}(z_1-z_2)$$
Or
$$y=\frac{1}{2}(c_1+ic_2)z_1+\frac{1}{2}(c_1-ic_2)z_2$$
So taking
$$b_1=\frac{1}{2}(c_1+ic_2)$$
$$b_2=\frac{1}{2}(c_1-ic_2)$$
We have found what we were looking for.